# What are the benefits of AngularJS dependency injection?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have been working with Angular for some time now, and I fail to see how it is an improvement from my previous way of coding.

First, I can't see what's wrong with having a central object to hold your project. After all, the injector is a singleton that looks up your dependencies into a central place, so Angular does have a central object, it's just hidden. Namespacing doesn't necessarily mean coupling, if it's done properly. And even when it's done, you don't need every single object of your code to be loosely coupled with the others. Besides, anytime you create a standalone JS script, you have to wrap it into Angular to make them play nice together.

Second, it's very verbose to declare all your dependencies everytime (especially with minification), so there is no gain from the readability point of view compared to proper namespacing.

Third, the performance gain is minimal. It forces me to use singletons everywhere, but I can do that on my own if I need to, and most of the time, I don't (network and DOM manipulations are my bottleneck, not JS objects).

In the end, I like the "enhanced" HTML and the automatic two-way bindings, but I can't see how the injection makes it any better than the way other frameworks deal with dependencies, given that it doesn't even provide dynamic loading like require.js. I haven't see any use case where I say to myself "oh, this is where it's so much better than before, I see" while coding.

Could you explain to me what benefits this technical choice brings to a project?

I can see only one for now: convention and best practice enforcement. It's a big one to create a lib ecosystem, but for now I don't see the fruit of it in the Angular community.

Comment: Unit Testing is one of major advantage using DI in angular

Comment: If you don't write a response and use only comments, I can't vote. Plus, I need more information on how DI make unit testing better. If you write decoupled components with getters and setters, having a central namespace doesn't cause problems with unit tests. So what does it bring to the table that I missed ?

Comment: Dependency injection shows exactly what a class needs, in order to perform its tasks based on its given responsibility. You are clearly defining what it consumes through its constructor, rather than hiding the actual requirements in order for the class to do its work, this makes it much more readable, in turn easier to maintain.

This is why it allows things to be tested easier, it's clear what goes where as you expose them directly through the seams (constructors) of your application code base. That's my understanding.

Comment: You may want to write that as an answer cause I'd upvote it.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide -
 Why Depencency Injection?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#why-dependency-injection-)

Answer (score 7):

**For me** there are few aspects of how Angular's dependency injection is improving my projects, which I will list here. I hope that this will show you how OTHERS can benefit from it, but if you are well organised and experienced JS developer, then perhaps it might not be the same case for you. I think at some point this is just the matter of developing your own tools and coding guide.

### Unified, declarative dependency resolving

JS is dynamic language (that's new, huh?) which gives a lot of power and even more responsibility to the programmer. Components can interact with each other on various ways by passing around all sorts of objects: regular objects, singletons, functions, etc. They can even make use of blocks of code which were not even mentioned to be used by other components.

JS has never had (and most likely never will) a unified way of declaring public, private or package (module) scopes like other languages have (Java, C, C#). Of course there are ways of encapsulating logic, but ask any newcomer to the language and he will simply don't know how to use it.

What I like about DI (not only in Angular, but in general) is the fact that you can list dependencies to your component, and you are not troubled how this dependency got constructed. This is very important for me, especially that DI in Angular allows you to resolve both kinds of components: these from the framework itself (like `$http`), or custom ones (like my favorite `eventBus` which I'm using to wrap `$on` event handlers).

Very often I look at the declaration of a service and I know what it does and how it does it just by looking at dependencies!

If I was to construct and/or make use of all those objects deep in the component itself, then I would always have to analyze implementation thoroughly and check it from various aspects. If I see `localStorage` in dependencies list, I know for the fact that I'm using HTML5 local storage to save some data. I don't have to look for it in the code.

### Lifespan of components

We don't need to bother anymore about order of initialization of certain components. If `A` is dependent on `B` then DI will make sure that `B` is ready when `A` needs it.

### Unit testing

It helps a lot to mock out components when you are using DI. For instance, if you have controller: `function Ctrl($scope, a, b, c, d)` then you instantly know what it is dependent on. You inject proper mocks, and you are making sure that all parties talking and listening to your controller are isolated. If you have troubles writing tests then you most likely messed up levels of abstraction or are violating design principles (Law Of Diameter, Encapsulation, etc.)

### Good habits

Yes, most likely you could use namespacing to properly manage the lifespan of your objects. Define singleton where its needed and make sure that noone messes up your private members.
But honestly, would you need that if the framework can do it for you?
I haven't been using JS "the right way" just until I learned Angular. It's not that I didn't care, I just didn't have to since I was using JS just for some tweeks of UI, primarly based on jquery.

Now its different, I got a nice framework which forces me a bit to keep up with good practices, but it also gives me great power to extend it and make use of the best features that JS has.

Of course poor programmers can still break even the best tool, but from what I've learned by recently reading "JS the good parts" by D. Crockford people were doing reeeeeealy nasty stuff with it. Thanks to great tools like jQuery, Angular and others we now have some nice tool which helps to write good JS applications and sticking to best practices while doing so.

### Conclusion

As you have pointed out, you CAN write good JS applications by doing at least those three things:

1. Namespacing - this avoids adding stuff to global namespace, avoids potential conflicts and allows for resolving proper components easily where needed
2. Creating reusable components / modules - by, for instance, using function module pattern and explicitly declaring private and public members
3. Managing dependencies between components - by defining singletons, allowing for retrieving dependencies from some 'registry', disallowing of doing certain stuff when certain conditions are not meet

Angular simply does that by:

- Having `$injector` which manages dependencies between components and retrieves them when needed
- Forcing to use factory function which has both PRIVATE and PUBLIC APIs.
- Let the components talk to each other either directly (by being dependent of one another) or by shared `$scope` chain.