# How dependency injection in Angular is useful since it doesn't solve anything apparently?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular5

How this can improve my code? How it can remove dependency ? I still don't see any benefit of using this ?

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'talk-list', 
  templateUrl: 'talks.html', 
  providers: [TalksAppBackend] 
}) 
class TalkList { 
  constructor(backend:TalksAppBackend) { 
    this.talks = backend.fetchTalks(); 
  } 
}
```

If i had used

TalksAppBackend t= new TalksAppBackend(); that would have been the same. Apart from syntactical difference how different it is?

Update:

Also, it's calling .fetchTalks(); that's not mocking. How its possible?

Comment: Pretend you store access session key (like JWT) in TalksAppBackend it will help you share it between components.

Comment: That would not be very testable.  You couldn't test TalkList functionality in an isolation. Since it would set off a chain of dependencies and your test would depend on many things. Which means it’s no longer isolated for testing. It’s hard to test the whole app e.g since it has many features, but a class that is isolated or all classes that are isolated can be easily tested.

Comment: @Axar but it's calling .fetchTalks(); that's not mocking. How its possible?

Comment: You can implement something that extends TalksAppBackend and override its public methods to return whatever you want instead of it calling the backend, thats mocking. Now you can control what TalksAppBackend retruns and then you can test the TalkList class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's a bad question for StackOverflow.
But it deserves the answer. So here is it.

**If you don't use Dependency Injection**

The main difference is that if you don't use DI (dependency injection) then your code MUST know how to create all of its dependencies. You may have tons of components using tons of services. The services may rely on other services, like `TalksAppBackend` may require `HttpClient` service. And your code must create dependencies for its dependencies. Like

`TalksAppBackend t = new TalksAppBackend(new HttpClient())`

And every your component must do that, creating a new instance of the TalksAppBackend and an instance of HttpClient. And if later the `TalksAppBackend` will require some logging service, you must update manually all your components to instantiate all the deps for `TalksAppBackend`. Such code is hard to maintain and it uses more memory than it should because it doesn't share instances.

**If you use Dependency Injection**

You just specify the module or a component which is responsible for creating instance of desired dependency. It will take care of it's dependencies as well. You components may just specify the desired class `TalksAppBackend` to be injected and should not care about whether or not it requires `HttpClient` or `Logger` or whatever. The DI does that job. And you have a fine control over it: a global service which is provided by a module will be instantiated just once. So your components can share the same instance.
And if you want to you may provide it on a component level so that many instances may be created and children components will have access to the only one instance that is needed.

And this approach also opens a way to mock dependencies and provide not the real `TalksAppBackend` service but rather a mock with fake answers that does not require network communication and running back-end to test if your component interprets the results accordingly. And you can do it without modifying the code of your component. So in this approach the component is focused for doing the thing it should do ONLY.

Comment: I think you should remove the first line because this is a great question and a good answer which would help a lot of people I believe.

Comment: So those are the benefits of DI. What are the costs? There certainly is a lot of syntactic overhead. Is there also cognitive overhead with all the extra indirection? These things need to be weighed against each other. And you need to consider the concrete usecase and context of where it is being used. The question is: For what YOU are doing, do you even need DI? Does it help you? Does it bring you joy? If it's just a headache, then don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefits of it

1. code with new key word is hard to test in a large application.
2. important: consider you are instantiating a class with new keyword. And after few day you want to change/add parameters to dependent class constructor. Then you need to change your code wherever you have used the instance of the same class. this will be a huge deal in an large project
3. Instances of dependencies created by a class that needs those dependencies are local to the class and cannot share data and logic

Answer (score 0):

It's good question. There alot of benefits of it. You can read about it on the same subject in AngularJS here: [What are the benefits of AngularJS dependancy injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792524/what-are-the-benefits-of-angularjs-dependancy-injection)

But for me, the key is the tests. If you do unit tests of this component, you can inject easilly a mock of `TalksAppBackend` and then isolate the component from their dependency in a unit test. By doing `TalksAppBackend t= new TalksAppBackend();` in the code, you will not be able to do unit test on it.

Comment: but it's calling .fetchTalks(); that's not mocking. How its possible?